# how to access class methods from the jquery events through on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a "component" sort of thing so that there is this HTML5 code along with accompanying javascript code so that I can use it as many times as I like. So first take a look at Html5 component code

```
<div class="listEditor" id="myStringList">
<div id="list" >
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="editor">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10  pull-left">
                <input type="text" id="sentenceText" class="form-control input-sm" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Add to list">@Html.GlyphIcon("plus")</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the accompanying code that should make it work.

```
class listEditor {
constructor(id) {
    this.componentSelector = 'div#' + id;
    this.component = $(this.componentSelector);
    this.listSelector = this.componentSelector + " div#list ul";

    $(this.componentSelector + " div#list ul li a").on("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
    });

    $(this.componentSelector + " div#editor button").on("click", function (evt) {
        var txt = $(this).parent().parent().find("input:text").val();
        addItem(txt);
    });

}

clear() {
    $(this.listSelector).empty();
}

addItem(text) {
    var item = '<li><a href="#" title="click to remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a><text>' + text + '</text></li>';
    $(this.listSelector).append(item);
}
removeListItem(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
 }

getData() {
    var data = [];

    this.component.children("div#list ul li").each(function (idx, li) {
        var txt = $(this).children("text").first().text();
        data.push(txt);
    });

    return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
}
```

Problem is that in any of the ON() events I cannot call the class methods. every method is undefined. doesn't matter if I call directly or use this.method() [i think in on() this refers to the control?]

Comment: You're calling the class methods inside the scope of the `on()` functions. What I would do is save the class instance of `this` in another variable so you can access it inside of the `on()` functions. For example `classThis = this`. Then inside `on()`, call the methods: `classThis.addItem()`

Comment: Be simpler to do this as a jQuery plugin

Comment: I'm a newbie in jquery so I cannot do such thing as plugins

Comment: Actually less complicated than your current approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your event handlers are called as anonymous functions by `on`, and `this` is the `currentTarget` of the event. To prevent that, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the
>   enclosing execution context (the class instance in this case) is used.

However, now you'll have to get a reference to the clicked event manually - `$(evt.currentTarget)`:

```
$(this.componentSelector + " div#editor button").on("click", (evt) => {
  var txt = $(evt.currentTarget).parent().parent().find("input:text").val();
  addItem(txt);
});
```

Comment: but now the alink click is not working. it doesn't even fire

Comment: The remove link?

Comment: The remove link won't work because you are adding list elements dynamically, and you bind the event once when you instantiate the class. Use event delegation - `$(this.componentSelector + " div#list ul").on("click", "a", (evt) => { /.../ });`

Comment: oh you are a guru, yes it worked like a charm .....though i didn't understand 
 the difference at all

Comment: When you use the standard form, the event is bounded to existing elements. When you use event delegation, the event is bounded to the parent, but it react to clicks on only a certain element. In this way, you can add/remove elements without worrying about event handling. Read about event delegation in [.on() docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).