# Handling of jQuery event using class method changes context

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

is someway possible to get class context from the inside of its method which is used as jQuery event handler? Following example should explain everything:

```
class EventHandler {
    constructor() {
        this.msg = 'I am event handler';
    }
    
    handle_on_click(event) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.msg);
    }
}

let handler = new EventHandler();
handler.handle_on_click(null);
// print:
// EventHandler {msg: 'I am event handler'}
// I am event handler

let $a = $('<a href="#">Test</a>').on('click', handler.handle_on_click);
$a.trigger('click');
// print:
// <a href="#">Test</a>
// undefined
```

Obviously the context was changed in the case of calling `handler.handle_on_click` via jQuery event, but is there way to get original context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before this answer I've tried to find the solution, but I was not successfull. And as it used to be, I found it a moment after. It is duplicate of this question [how to access class methods from the jquery events through on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114013/how-to-access-class-methods-from-the-jquery-events-through-on).

Explanation is that `this` is a pointer to current context, which in the case of calling via jQuery `on` is the element. If you need to get class context, it is necessary to call handler using arrow function:

```
class EventHandler {
    constructor() {
        this.msg = 'I am event handler';
    }
    
    handle_on_click(event) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.msg);
    }
}

let handler = new EventHandler();
handler.handle_on_click(null);
// print:
// EventHandler {msg: 'I am event handler'}
// I am event handler

let $a = $('<a href="#">Test</a>').on('click', (event) => handler.handle_on_click(event));
$a.trigger('click');
// print:
// EventHandler {msg: 'I am event handler'}
// I am event handler
```